# What nuclear fusion reactions occur to form lithium in the sun?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, sun

- Hydrogen nuclei (deuterium) fuse together to form a He-4 nucleus.

I looked up about how lithium exists in the sun and all of the results on Google I looked through kind of dodge the question and emphasize that there is 1% lithium in the sun. I can only assume it comes from the nuclear fusion reaction between He-3 and deuterium, and it is unstable to experience alpha decay back into protium again (due to too low N/Z ratio), otherwise stable lithium nuclei would continue fusing but the amount of nuclei with 4 or more protons in the sun is apparently negligible so this isn't the case. How is there lithium in the sun? Thanks.

Comment: seems to be from the big bang see https://astronomycommunity.nature.com/posts/revealing-the-secret-life-of-lithium-in-sun-like-stars

Comment: @annav So the lithium from the big bang remains stable and resistant to decay/fusion even in the sun's environment?

Comment: While it is produced in the [pp II branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain#The_p%E2%80%93p_II_branch), I think you're largely wondering more about the open(?) question about Lithium production overall. BB Nucleosynthesis & cosmic ray spallation are the two processes I'm aware of, though I last looked at this like 7-8 years ago (i.e., when I was in grad school).

Comment: Discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium#Astronomical).

Comment: @AshtonDowling  There are stable lithium isotopes. https://world-nuclear.org/information-library/current-and-future-generation/lithium.aspx,   It is the From the  previous ink,, "Astronomers regard lithium as fragile, easily destroyed in the hot interiors of stars. Observations of lithium on the surface of stars have confirmed that it is gradually destroyed as stars get older." It is the density in the cosmos that changes  with time from interactions, and is the unknown how.